# SCons does not find file it should build itself

Tags: scons

I have a simple SConstruct file to build the google test library with MinGW:

```
env = Environment(platform='posix')  # necessary to use gcc and not MS
env.Append(CPPPATH=['googletest/'])
env.Append(CCFLAGS=[('-isystem', 'googletest/include/'), '-pthread'])
obj = env.Object(source='googletest/src/gtest-all.cc')
# linking skipped due to error search
# env.Append(LINKFLAGS=['-rv'])
# bin = env.StaticLibrary(target='libgtest', source=[obj])
```

The script resides in the main `googletest\` folder. When running it - with or without linking - the output is this:

```
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
g++ -o googletest\src\gtest-all.o -c -isystem googletest/include/ -pthread -Igoogletest googletest\src\gtest-all.cc
scons: *** [googletest\src\gtest-all.o] The system cannot find the file specified
+-.
  +-googletest
  | +-googletest\src
  |   +-googletest\src\gtest-all.cc
  |   +-googletest\src\gtest-all.o
  |   | +-googletest\src\gtest-all.cc
  |   | +-googletest\src\gtest-death-test.cc
  |   | +-googletest\src\gtest-filepath.cc
  |   | +-googletest\src\gtest-port.cc
  |   | +-googletest\src\gtest-printers.cc
  |   | +-googletest\src\gtest-test-part.cc
  |   | +-googletest\src\gtest-typed-test.cc
  |   | +-googletest\src\gtest.cc
  |   | +-googletest\src\gtest-internal-inl.h
  |   +-googletest\src\gtest-death-test.cc
  |   +-googletest\src\gtest-filepath.cc
  |   +-googletest\src\gtest-internal-inl.h
  |   +-googletest\src\gtest-port.cc
  |   +-googletest\src\gtest-printers.cc
  |   +-googletest\src\gtest-test-part.cc
  |   +-googletest\src\gtest-typed-test.cc
  |   +-googletest\src\gtest.cc
  |   +-googletest\src\libgtest-all.a
  |     +-googletest\src\gtest-all.o
  |       +-googletest\src\gtest-all.cc
  |       +-googletest\src\gtest-death-test.cc
  |       +-googletest\src\gtest-filepath.cc
  |       +-googletest\src\gtest-port.cc
  |       +-googletest\src\gtest-printers.cc
  |       +-googletest\src\gtest-test-part.cc
  |       +-googletest\src\gtest-typed-test.cc
  |       +-googletest\src\gtest.cc
  |       +-googletest\src\gtest-internal-inl.h
  +-SConstruct
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

I also tried to build the library in one line: `env.StaticLibrary(source='googletest/src/gtest-all.cc')` - the result is the same.

Just executing the actuall g++ call gives me the object file I want.
What confuses me is that SCons should see the object file as an artifact it creates itself. I wondering why it tries to use it before it is finished. So what am I missing here? How can I make SCons wait until the compiling is done?

BTW: I just have some experience in using SCons and and did tweak a script once a while - but I do not really have profound knowledger about it.

Versions used: SCons 3.0.1, Python 3.6.3, MinGW 7.3.0

Comment: Can you please show us the output of "`scons --tree=all`"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work?

```
env = Environment(tools=['mingw','gnulink','ar'])  # You should specify the tools
env.Append(CPPPATH=['googletest/'])
env.Append(CCFLAGS=[('-isystem', 'googletest/include/'), '-pthread'])
obj = env.Object(source='googletest/src/gtest-all.cc')
# linking skipped due to error search
# env.Append(LINKFLAGS=['-rv'])
# bin = env.StaticLibrary(target='libgtest', source=[obj])
```

Comment: Indeed, after I read `PATH` as well (`Environment(ENV = {'PATH' : os.environ['PATH']}, tools=['mingw','gnulink','ar'])`) it worked. Reading `PATH` didn't change anything in my original attempt. So, what do I get from this? `platform=posix`  just does not pick the gcc toolset on WIndows as I assumed?

Comment: no. Posix says you are on a posix system. Windows is not that.  You need to pick the tools individually if you don't want to use SCons's defaults.   BTW.. what's the path to your mingw install? Trying to improve the default search path for such.

Comment: Did you see documents or a webpage somewhere which suggested setting platform to posix would work?

Comment: No, that was my very own thought. I just wanted to overrule the default Windows tool chain. The path to my MINGW is just like `C:\MinGW\bin` and exported as an environment variable. Which is the one I use instead of the unspecific`%PATH%` now.

Comment: BTW: Yes setting `platform='posix'` was - let's say - very optimistic. Though I still don't get, why this lets scons not wait to finish the file. I didn't even had the idea that this could be the fault.

Comment: The issue is the file separators.. so with posix x\b\c = a file.  With platform = win32 x\b\c = directory x\b and file c..  By incorrectly setting platform to posix you got a mix of the above and chaos ensued with the dependencies..